# Apache Spark 2.1.0 - Basic Setup: worker node not connecting with master node

Tags: ubuntu, networking, apache-spark, virtualbox, cluster-computing

I'm trying to get two VMs running Apache Spark to connect; a master and a worker. I'm using VirtualBox and a [host-only](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) network adaptor. The VMs are able to `ping` each other but when I start the worker it doesn't appear in the master's web UI.

I'm using static IPs with the master's being `10.10.10.2` and worker's `10.10.10.3`

My `spark-env.sh` file is configured to include:

```
SPARK_MASTER_IP=10.10.10.2
```

I first launch the master node:

```
./start-master.sh

starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /usr/lib/spark/logs/spark-masternode-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-masternode.out
```

Then the worker:

```
./start-slave.sh spark://10.10.10.2:7077

starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /usr/lib/spark/logs/spark-modelnode1-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-modelnode1.out
```

The resulting output of the master node GUI:

[image: screenshot]

If I `nmap 10.10.10.2` from the worker:

```
Nmap scan report for 10.10.10.2
Host is up (0.00035s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

I'm not sure whether that's relevant but it doesn't show anything at `7077`

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Are you sure there are no firewall rules (see `iptables -L`) that are blocking connections?

Comment: @JamesFry, no rules were listed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Completely missed that you were using Spark 2.1.0, sorry!

Comment: @JamesFry, I should have listed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SPARK_MASTER_IP` has been deprecated and is no longer used in Spark 2.x. You can use:

- `SPARK_MASTER_HOST` environmental variable
- `-h` / `--host` option for `sbin/start-master.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Changed it and it worked straight away!